# Ubuntu boot loader stuck at Dell logo in Ubuntu-W10 dual boot on Dell laptop

Tags: dual-boot, startup

**PC** - Dell G3

**specs** - i7-H variant 1 TB HDD + 256GB SSD  and 16 GB RAM

**dual boot W10 and Ubuntu 20.04**

On booting and selecting Ubuntu in grub2 menu, the screen **transitions to Dell logo and *freezes***.

Note that my Ubuntu setup **was working before this successfully** for about a month.

Expert users, what should I do to successfully start Ubuntu again?

I am a relative novice, thanks for the help and support in advance.

Comment: On the Plymouth boot animation screen, you can press "Escape" to show the boot log. Do this, and look for anything suspicious in this log (for example: hanging on things like "A start job is running..."). Although if the system completely freezes you might have problems with Escape...

Comment: It showed acpi bios error @Daniel Massey

Comment: Does recovery mode (In Grub2 menu: Advanced Options for Ubuntu --> Ubuntu ... (Recovery Mode)) boot at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution to: Stuck on Dell logo in Dual Boot Dell Machine**

**Machine Information:**

- Model: Dell G5 5587
- Processor: Intel core i7-8750H
- Ram: 16GB
- Graphics: NVIDIA 1060 GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile
- SSD: 256GB
- HDD: 1TB
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

**Scenario:**

- Updated packages, drivers, and softwares using *Software Updater* as usual.
- Restarted the machine as suggested.
- Dell logo freezes in the laptop and on the connected second display(VGA) I could login.
- Network connectivity and Bluetooth connection was missing.
- I disconnected the second display and restarted the machine.
- Stuck on the Dell logo screen after selecting the Ubuntu from Grub menu. Waited for more than 5 minutes but it did not change.

**Solution:**

- Selected *Ubuntu Advanced Options* from the Grub menu.
- Selected the recovery mode for the latest Kernel version. For me it was: `Linux 5.4.0-60-generic (recovery mode)`
- Selected the `dpgk Repair broken packages`.
- Pressed `y` and then `Enter`.
- Selected `Resume Resume to normal boot`.
- Logged in to the OS, it was flickering on the second display.
- Got network connection and Bluetooth connection.
- Update the packages using `sudo apt-get update`
- Changed settings in `Software Updater`>`Updates`> `Notify me of a new Ubuntu version` > `Any version`.
- Closed the `Software Updater` and opened it again.
- Got notification of a new upgrade of `Ubuntu 20.10` version.
- Clicked `Upgrade`.
- Followed on screen instructions to upgrade `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` to `Ubuntu 20.10`.
- Restarted the machine.
- The Dell logo is not freezing anymore.
- Restarted the machine several times to confirm the normal behavior of the machine. Everything was working as expected.

Comment: So the solution to 20.04 LTS is to update to 20.10?